# Extracting column from a multi section file

Tags: linux, bash

not sure what exactly to write in title section. I have a scenario where I want to extract a specific column from multi section file. For example:

```
unit     id     ip
32       43     5.5.5.1

machine  price
431-P    45k
S-34     10k
```

I want to extract the contents under machine column. Any idea how i can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the machine section is the last section, like in your example, then you could use awk to look for `machine` in the first field of the record and just print any record found after that point:

```
 awk '$1=="machine"{machineSection=1}machineSection==1{print $0}' test.txt
```

This test the first field `$1` to see if it's `machine`. If it is then it sets the `machineSection` variable to 1. Then it tests to see if `machineSection` variable is 1 then it will print the record out.

Comment: Thanks @JNevill, it works great. Should print $0 be print $1 as it is printing both machine and price section?

Comment: `$0` is the entire record, where `$1` is just the first field. I guess it depends on what you want to print from that section.

Comment: Thanks, i wanted to print the column under machine.

Comment: Oh! I gotcha. Then yes, $1 is the right way to go!

Comment: if there is another column section under machine, how can i ensure that I get only machine section?

Comment: You could add in a new block that has a condition that identifies a new section. Something like `awk '$1=="machine"{machineSection=1} $1==""{machineSection=0} machineSection==1{print $0}' test.txt` where we toggle that variable to 0 when we find nothing in $1. That might have to be tweaked depending on how you identify a new section, but it should get you close.

Comment: '$1=="machine"{machineSection=1} $1=="section_under_machine"{machineSection=0} machineSection==1{print $1}' test.txt, worked like a charm, Thanks again